# Hive Length outputs more than seen

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to run a hive query which should join two table with matching records. However, it never matches but i have the record in the other table. When i do length of a given string it outputs 27, but it should be just 12.
When i download the output file from s3 then i see weird row like

> U S 3 F F 1 2 1 4 9 3 3

but in hive console it see it as

> US3FF1214933

Also i cannot query the row with

`select * from table where item like "US3FF1214933";`

It is totally a mess right now and trimming also does not work for me.
I am in need of help.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: do you know what is that character in between? possibly it isn't a space but something else. run `od -c` on the file holding this data row to find out. That would be my first step

Comment: Thank you , it gives me \0 between the characters. I will try to replace them with "". What would be easiest way to format this file properly without these characters.

Comment: where/how is this file generated? do you want to fix the problem at the source or just edit the generated data file to remove the binary nulls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to legato for giving me an idea to investigate this by doing
od -c and seeing actual characters between the string.

And after in hive query using regexp_replace(ExString,'\0',"") to replace the weird characters with empty string solved my issue.